# How to sort Dataset where each row include a sequence of strings and integers

Tags: string-manipulation, dataset, sorting, integer-sequence

I got this type of data :

```
initDataS = Dataset@<|"Count" -> <|ID01 -> 41667 "Train",
ID02 -> 23288 "Tail" + 18379 "Train",
ID03 -> 30907 "Tail" + 10760 "Train",
ID04 -> 34058 "Tail" + 7100 "Train" + 509 "Loop",
ID05 -> 36256 "Tail" + 5411 "Train",
ID06 -> 37548 "Tail" + 3700 "Train" + 419 "Loop"|>|>
```

[image: Formated InitDataS]

I would like to efficiently sort it out in this way :

```
FinalDataS = Dataset@ <|"ID01" -> <|"Train" -> 41667, "Tail" -> 0, "Loop" -> 0|>,
"ID02" -> <|"Train" -> 18379, "Tail" -> 23288, "Loop" -> 0|>,
"ID03" -> <|"Train" -> 10760, "Tail" -> 30907, "Loop" -> 0|>,
"ID04" -> <|"Train" -> 7100, "Tail" -> 34058, "Loop" -> 509|>,
"ID05" -> <|"Train" -> 5411, "Tail" -> 36256, "Loop" -> 0|>,
"ID06" -> <|"Train" -> 3700, "Tail" -> 37548, "Loop" -> 419|> |>
```

[image: Formated FinalDataS]

How could i do this ?
Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should we wish to force the output columns appear in an explicitly specified order, then we can use this:

```
columns[ls_][e_] := <| FirstCase[e, n_ # :> # -> n, # -> 0, {0, 1}] & /@ ls |>

initDataS[Values, All, columns[{"Train", "Tail", "Loop"}]]
```

[image: Dataset screenshot]

This also allows us to select only a subset of the available columns:

```
initDataS[Values, All, columns[{"Loop", "Train"}]]
```

[image: subset Dataset screenshot]

Comment: Thanks, this help me a lot

Answer (score 4):

```
Block[{Missing = (0 &)}, 
 Transpose[Transpose@
   initDataS[1, All, Association[# /. Times | Plus -> List /. {a_, b_String} :> b -> a] &]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Perfectly working

Comment: So the `Transpose` forces the dataset to see that it is missing data and apply the `Missing`?